# Prevent Refresh of SSI

Tags: server-side-includes

I have a few SSIs that repeat across many pages within my site - in particular my navigation tree which allow a user to expand or collapse nodes within the tree.

I'd like to prevent the same .shtml file from loading if it's already been loaded in a previous page - this way when a user clicks on one of the entries in my navigation tree, the entire tree isn't refreshed on to target page (which causes the user's current node to be collapsed).  Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put the navigation tree in a separate frame (not an iframe), which brings along problems of its own; since the include's happening on the server side, anything in the included content which causes a page refresh is going to refresh the entire page, without respect for what's included via SSI and what isn't. With the tree in a frame of its own, and its links modified to point to the content frame, you won't have this problem -- of course, using frames to solve this problem will just give you another problem.

A slightly better option would be to use cookies and Javascript to record which nodes of the tree are expanded. You could bind a click handler to each node expander/contracter which would update a Javascript object representing the state of the tree, and on each click event, flatten that object into a string and store it via document.cookie. That way, you can persist the tree status into the next page load, where an onload handler can expand the nodes listed in the cookie to return the tree to the state it had when the page-reloading link was clicked.

Something like this might work, assuming the presence of jQuery, either a browser with native JSON support or an equivalent library loaded, that your node expander/contracter controls are implemented as <a> tags with class "node-control", that the control for an expanded node has class "expanded" (presumably given by a pre-existing click handler), and that each one has an id attribute which uniquely identifies its position in the tree.

```
 // begin "persistent-node-state.js"

 window.nodesExpanded = {};

 // do the following on document load completion: 
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // check for a nodesExpanded value in the cookie
   var cookieMatch = document.cookie.match(/nodesExpanded=(.*?)\;/);
   if (cookieMatch) { // no nodesExpanded cookie found -- do nothing
     // we found a nodesExpanded cookie; let's unserialize its value into
     // window.nodesExpanded
     window.nodesExpanded = JSON.parse(cookieMatch[1]);
   };

   // iterate through the nodesExpanded object's keys, which are IDs of controls whose
   // nodes we want to expand (if we didn't find a cookie, then window.nodesExpanded 
   // is an empty object, making this loop a very complicated no-op)
   for (node_id in nodesExpanded) {
     // call the pre-existing click handler to expand the node
     jQuery('a.node_control#' + node_id).click();
   };

   // now that that's done, give each node control an additional click handler which 
   // puts its state into window.nodesExpanded and updates the cookie
   jQuery('a.node-control').click(function(i,el) {
     var node_id = jQuery(el).attr('id');

     // if this control's node is expanded...
     if (jQuery(el).hasClass('expanded')) {
       // ...then add the control's id as a key in window.nodesExpanded...
       window.nodesExpanded[node_id] = true;
     }
     else {
       // ...otherwise remove any existing key in window.nodesExpanded with this 
       // node's ID
       window.nodesExpanded[node_id] = undefined;
     };

     // store the updated state in the cookie so it'll persist across page loads
     document.cookie('nodesExpanded=' + JSON.stringify(window.nodesExpanded));
   });
 });

 // end "persistent-node-state.js"
```

Of course, all of this can be done without jQuery, but it doesn't cost much to load that library -- you don't even have to download it, but can [load it from Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) -- and it makes everything to do with Javascript so much easier that there's no very good reason not to do so unless you need to support very old (e.g. pre-IE6) browsers, or something of that general nature.

Similarly, all of the various cues (i.e., how to identify a node expand/contract control, how to tell whether it's expanded, how to fire the event which causes a node to expand or contract, &c.) can be modified at need; it's hard to tailor an example to your situation in the absence of a site link or some sample code, so I went for something that's as generic as possible while still demonstrating the basic idea, and which shouldn't be too hard to edit to taste.

Comment: I figured something like this would have to happen.  I guess I could also use sessionStorage to store the current node of the user in the navigation tree.

Comment: Sure, but why incur an HTML5 dependency when you don't really have to? I mean, you're using SSI, you're firmly rooted in the past as it stands...

Answer (score 0):

Server side includes are just that, server side. If you have the same include file in multiple pages, it will be included each time. Apache (or IIS) will see to that. On the other hand, if the same file is included in multiple include files when building a single "page", you can set a variable in the included file and test for it in each place the file gets included. I do that with a configuration file that sets global variables for my site.